# Cannot find symbol which is defined in another dynamic library

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I wrote a program which loads `a.so` (via `dlopen`), and inside of `a.so`, I `dlopen` `b.so`. `b.so` uses some functions implemented in `a.so`. I got this error at runtime:

```
symbol lookup error, undefined symbol
```

After `nm a.so`, I got this undefined symbol is in type "T".
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please provide more details, or at least a [mcve]?

Comment: What flags do you use with `dlopen()`?  Please show the sample code — it needn't be very complex at all, but it does need to be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use RTLD_GLOBAL flag when dlopen a.so, then the symbols defined by a.so will be made available for symbol resolution of subsequently loaded libraries.

Answer (score 0):

When `b.so` is dynamically loaded using `dlopen()` it won't be aware of symbols in the caller executable (or shared object in your case). Therefore you'll get the "undefined symbol" error. The calling hierarchy does matter here, it's not becoming a big pool of all symbols once it's loaded.

In order to do achieve this functionality, you could define two functions in `b.so`, and one in `a.so`:

1. A function that receives a *callback* function (and saves/registers it).
2. A function that executes the callback function (that was registered earlier).

Then, in `a.so` you would have a function that wraps this symbol that was undefined, let's call this function `wrapper()`. And then in `a.so` you would:

1. Dynamically load `b.so`.
2. Call the register function from `b.so` giving it as an argument `wrapper()` (defined in `a.so`), because it expects a callback.
3. Execute the second function from `b.so` that will practically call `wrapper()`.

Then you got what you wanted in the first place - to execute `wrapper()` and without calling a function that is defined in `a.so` from `b.so`.